Postnikov invariant of crossed square
Is there a reference where Postnikov invariants of the classifying space of a crossed square have been computed ? I am especially interested in the computation of the third Postnikov invariant $B\mathcal{C}^{(2)}\overset{k_3}{\rightarrow} K(\pi_3B\mathcal{C},4)//\pi_1B\mathcal{C}$. Here I denoted $B\mathcal{C}^{(2)}$ the (pointed) homotopy 2-Type associated to the classifying space $B\mathcal{C}$ of the crossed square $\mathcal{C}$.
